# Translating WP Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My company bought WP theme [Inceptio](http://themeforest.net/item/inceptio-responsive-multipurpose-html-template/full_screen_preview/4213432) and now i try to translate this theme on Russian. I opened en_US.mo file in Notpad++ and changed English words to Russian. Nothing happened. I want change only a few words - Home to Главная in the main menyu and words in the footer. Can i change this words exactly in the themes files and where i can do it. Thank you for any help!
Our site http://bpe24.ru/

Comment: These are the usual steps: http://www.cryoutcreations.eu/wordpress/how-to-translate-a-wordpress-theme (although the main menu is usually edited inside WP itself, and the words in the footer may be in the footer file - take a look)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin can definetely help you : http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/

Of course  if the template is not internationalization ready you might have to look for the strings in the theme folder and replace each STRING with __('STRING')

See also http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers